# Condition number of 2x2 nonsingular matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I am working on the problem that I have to show why the infinity-norm condition number and 1-norm condition number of 2x2 nonsingular matrix are equal.

MY ATTEMPT: Since $I=AA^{-1}$, the condition number of A is a norm of $I$. Therefore the $\infty$-norm and 1-norm condition number are same.

Does my argument seem reasonable? If not, what can I do with this problem?

Comment: it is not reasonable

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> Since $I=AA^{-1}$, the condition number of $A$ is a norm of $I$

is completely unfounded, and it even makes no sense. Does this mean that $I$ has several different norms, i.e. is *every* condition number a norm of $I$?

Furthermore, you did not describe how this in any way implies that the two condition numbers are the same.

---

I would suggest you re-start your proof. First, write down the *definition* of a condition number, and the definitions of both the $1$ and $\infty$ norms. Edit your question with those things, and we will be able to help you further.

Comment: Yes, I agree that  it was my poor attempt.

Comment: For reasoning out my failed attempt, since condition number is $||A|| ||A^-1||$  and 1-norm seeks maximum sum of column vector of A and infinity-norm is maximum sum of row vector of A. So i thought it would be related.

Comment: @wrenyoong Just... slow down. You have a lot of "hunches" and "ideas", but that's 5% of math. Once you have a hunch, you go and slowly, rigorously see them through. That is what you need to do. Write down the definitions, write down what you want to prove, and what you know.

Comment: It turns out that I got my inverse definition mixed up as flipping c and b. Thank you!